# to create and insert number in a sorted linked list in java

Tags: java

I am trying to create and insert numbers in circular sorted linked list but i am getting an error as 
Null Pointer Exception in line no. 45.
plzz anyone could see what i did wrong here.

```
public class nodes {
    private int data;
    private nodes next;

    public nodes(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    //standard getters and setters. See below if you really want to

    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter 0 to stop");
        nodes headnode =null;

        int n =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        while(n!=0){
            nodes insert = null;
            System.out.println("enter the value");

            int t =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            insert.setdata(t);

            nodetoinsert(insert, headnode);
        }
    }

    private static void nodetoinsert(nodes p, nodes headnode){
        nodes previousnode =null;

        if (headnode ==null){
            headnode.setdata(p.getdata());
        }else if(headnode.getdata()&gt;(p.getdata())){
            p.setNext(headnode);
        }else{
            nodes currentnode= headnode.getnext();

            if(currentnode.getnext() == null)
                 currentnode.setNext(headnode);

            while(currentnode.getdata()&lt;= p.getdata()&& currentnode !=headnode){
                previousnode =currentnode;
                currentnode =currentnode.getnext();
            }

            previousnode.setNext(p);
            p.setNext(currentnode);
        }
    }

    public void setdata(int data){
        this.data=data;
    }

    public int getdata(){
        return data;
    }

    public void setNext(nodes next){
        this.next=next;
    }

    public nodes getnext(){
        return this.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark line 45. I guess your problem is this here: `nodes insert = null;` and then `insert.setdata(t);`, which might throw the exception. But you could also post the accordant stacktrace.

Comment: This is java. I suggest you write class names starting with a capital, like `Nodes`. Methos ("functions of objects") are usually written camelCase. Your `nodetoinsert` would become `nodeToInsert`. It is more readable and IDEs like Eclipse cope better with it. Like to know more of it? Here are the guidelines: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if (headnode ==null){

    headnode.setdata(p.getdata());

}
```

You call the setdata method on headnode, which is null => NPE. Same with the insert node.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:
1) `nodes headnode =null;`

That is still passed as null to `nodetoinsert(insert, headnode);` 
Initialize headnode. `nodes headnode =new nodes(0);`

2) You are trying to invoke a method on a null reference. please see below:

```
while(n!=0){
            **nodes insert = null;**
            System.out.println("enter the value");

            int t =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            **insert**.setdata(t);

            nodetoinsert(insert, headnode);
        }
```

Your nodes reference variable is not initialized. You need to initialize that nodes reference. something like below:

```
while(n!=0){
            nodes insert = new nodes(0);
            System.out.println("enter the value");

            int t =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            insert.setdata(t);

            nodetoinsert(insert, headnode);
        }
```

Let me know if you want any further help.